# Visual Basic 2010 Search datagrid but data was not complete

Tags: vb.net

I have create 2 combobox enable user to choose the departure and destination and search for available flight, but i am facing a problem here.

Before click on searching button, i can see the datagrid is showing all details, but once i click the search button, it search correct data but some details is missing, can anyone please advise me?

[Screenshot of Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz4vo.png)

Here is my coding:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    FlightDataGridView.DataSource = Me.FlightsDatabaseDataSet.Flight.Select("Departure= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' AND Destination= '" & ComboBox2.Text & "'")

End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the wrong way to filter data.  What you should be doing is binding your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`, binding that to the `DataGridView` and then setting the `Filter` of the `BindingSource`.  As you're using a typed `DataSet`, I'm guessing that you already have a `BindingSource`.  One would have been generated if you dragged the table from the Data Sources window onto the form.  In that case, your code should look something like this:

```
FlightBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Departure = '{0}' AND Destination = '{1}'",
                                           ComboBox1.Text,
                                           ComboBox2.Text)
```

Note the use of `String.Format` to improve the readability.

Comment: hi @jmcilhinney, thanks so much for your guidance, now i get what you mean, much appreciate here